# SignalR: "Protocol error: Unknown transport." when navigating to hub

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm trying to use ASP.NET Signalr for the first time - here's what I've done:
Created a new web project and added the following SignalR packages:

[image]

I've then created the following class:

```
[HubName("chat")]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Hello()
    {
        Clients.All.hello();
    }
}
```

And the following startup configuration:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

However whenever I navigate to

> localhost:(port)/api/signalr/chat

I get the following error:

> Protocol error: Unknown transport.

I'm running the latest browsers and have tried multiple different ones so what could be the issue?

Comment: You shouldn't need to navigate directly to that endpoint. You use javascript to connect to the hub: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client

Comment: your hub script should be at `/signalr/hubs`, if your SignalR is working you'll be able to navigate to that page while your site is running.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the api/ from the url, and just use localhost:(port)/signalr/chat